# How to make input's width equal to no. of words value?

Tags: javascript, css

If my value is xyz

I dont want inputs width = 100%
I want that inputs width will automatically resize equal to how many words are in input's value.

Comment: By 'words' you mean 'characters'?

Answer (score 2):

A little *hacky*, but I found the follwing to be one possible way to do it:

sample markup:

```
<input />
<span id="input-width-helper"></span>
```

css:

```
input {
  min-width: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

#input-width-helper {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
  /* extra styles would be needed, if the input has other styles
     affecting it's font, width, etc. */
}
```

js:

```
$('input').on('keydown', function () {
  var
    $this = $(this),
    $helper = $('#input-width-helper');

  setTimeout(function () {
    // the '+ 10' here is arbitrary to account for paddings/borders
    // if the hidden helper ('#input-width-helper') is styled correctly,
    // this could probably be removed
    $this.css('width', $helper.text($this.val()).width() + 10); 
  }, 0);
});
```

demo: http://jsbin.com/aqakus/3/

*note: of course this would need to be adepted to work with multiple inputs!*